# Div with position:fixed not visible in mobile Responsive design

Tags: html, image, position, fixed

I have a website with an online chat script integrated. We created a image button instead of default link provided by the company.

The div in which image reside is marked as position fixed and it is visible on the bottom right corner of the browser on the desktop.

If I open the same in mobile the div is not visible though the design is Responsive.

Below is the CSS that is used for both versions

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
 #theradome-proonto {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 30px;
 right: 12px;
 background: white;
 z-index: 99999;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
 #theradome-proonto {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 30px;
 right: 12px;
 background: white;
 z-index: 99999;
}
}
```

My website is http://www.theradome.com it is built in wordpress

Comment: Could you post a link to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `#theradome-proonto` in **modal.less** on **Line 95**

This css rule sets `display: none` for your `div#theradome-proonto`
That is the CSS rule which affects the proper displaying of your div.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
    #STM_root_elem, #theradome-proonto, .doctor_trusted {
        display: none !important;
}
```

**Try to override this by following CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    #theradome-proonto {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 30px;
        right: 12px;
        background: white;
        z-index: 99999;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        display: block !important; /* this line is important! */
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**
What is in your **style.css** on line **2673**?
Because when I open **style.css** in my browser, I see following comment on **line 2671** - `/* rules for all mobile resolutions (< 768)  */` which is followed by the CSS I've mentioned before.

If you can't find it, my last advice to you is - try to place the CSS I've added (this one with `display: block !important`) at the end of your **style.css**

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ramis but I didn't found the line "#theradome-proonto in modal.less on Line 95" Also I made above change and it didn't worked.

Comment: Ok, could you add `display: block !important` to your max-width media query in CSS? I'm not sure  you got me right, the `display: none !important` prevents the displaying of your div. so only change you've to apply is to find the line where it's and delete the ID (`#theradome-proonto`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I did the CSS change as suggested but no success. The only place where I could find #theradome-proonto is in style.css as given in my original question

Comment: Are you able to search for this - `#STM_root_elem, #theradome-proonto, .doctor_trusted`

Comment: No I searched through the source code and couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks Ramis, It is visible now. The link is not working but I will work on it.